# How can i get the list of users/groups who got access to a certain page or document library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, access, https

I want to use HTTP Request to get the list of users or groups who got access to a specific page or document library

Answer (score 0):

For page you can try this query for GET request to get all assigned permission of item. Example: {Url}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListTitle')/items(1)/roleassignments.
For list or library use EffectiveBasePermissions to get permissions of the user on a list. Example:
{Url} /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListTitle')/EffectiveBasePermissions

Comment: Thank you!
I am bit new this, basically what I am trying to do is run a flow to get the list of names of  users/groups who got access to a certain page or library and download to it an excel file. Is that possible?

Comment: I guess Yes, you can call REST requests from Flow for starting point you can read this topic: [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/guidance/working-with-send-sp-http-request) and after that you can prepare CSV in Flow and upload this CSV to SharePoint.